# segmentation fault while accessing a structure object

Tags: c

I am trying to implement heapsort programe in C language.
The whole program works until the last part when i am trying to print the sorted array.
By the time the sorting finishes, I am not able to access any element of the structure.
Please help me underatand the mistake.

The programe is as follows
    //programe to implement heap sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct MaxHeap
{
int size;
int* array;
};

void print_array(int arr[],int size)
{
int i;
printf("Entered print_array function\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   printf("%d ",arr[i]);
printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *p, int *q)
{
int temp=*p;
*p=*q;
*q=temp;
}

void heapify(struct MaxHeap* maxheap,int x)
{
if(maxheap->array[x] < maxheap->array[(2*x + 1)] && (2*x + 1) < maxheap->size)
   swap(&(maxheap->array[x]),&(maxheap->array[(2*x + 1)]));
if(maxheap->array[x] < maxheap->array[(2*x + 2)] && (2*x + 2) < maxheap->size)
   swap(&(maxheap->array[x]),&(maxheap->array[(2*x + 2)]));
}

struct MaxHeap* create_maxheap(int arr[],int size)
{
struct MaxHeap* maxheap = (struct MaxHeap*)malloc(sizeof(struct MaxHeap));
maxheap->size = size;
maxheap->array =arr; 
int i;
for(i=(maxheap->size-1)/2;i>=0;i--)
   heapify(maxheap,i);

return maxheap;
}

void heap_sort(struct MaxHeap* maxheap)
{
int i;
while(maxheap->size>0)
{
   swap(&(maxheap->array[0]),&(maxheap->array[maxheap->size]));
   maxheap->size--;
//   printf("maxheap->size is %d\n",maxheap->size);
   heapify(maxheap,0);
}
}

void main()
{
int tmp[] = {3,1,3};
int size = 3;
struct MaxHeap* maxheap=create_maxheap(tmp,size);

printf("The MaxHeap is created with size %d\n",maxheap->size);

heap_sort(maxheap);
printf("The array after sorting is \n");
print_array(maxheap->array,size);
}
```

The output is as follows

```
The MaxHeap is created with size 3
maxheap->size is 2
maxheap->size is 1
maxheap->size is 0
The array after sorting is 
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Did you run it with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) already?

Comment: It looks like your indexing is off, e.g. you call `heapify` with x = 1 and then access elements at 2*x+1, 2*x+2, which are both out of bounds.

Comment: `&(maxheap->array[maxheap->size])` will address one element beyond the allowable region of your array. Remember, in C/C++, arrays are zero-based and run to `(n-1)` for a sequence of length `n`.

Comment: You should do te checks for the error bound before accessing the (possible out-of-bound) entries. Swap the expressions around the `&&` in `heapify`.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent comments tell you what to do to fix your program

Here is what can be going wrong

There are several stack variables in main(). These will be layed out more or less contiguously on the stack. One of these is an array, 
and one of the comment suggest that code is trying to access the elements
out of bound.

The array is only 3 integers long, and code tries to write to 4th element
( i.e. index of 3 ), it *may* end up changing the size variable. Note that
I've used 'may' rather than 'will', as depending on the compiler options etc ,
 it can be some other variable, or even a unused padding space. This invalid
update of variable will be noticed when the variable is used the next time.

The problem with array out of bound writes is that the  problem and it's effect
can be in totally unrelated code, causing grief to the person debugging it, and
giving employment to almost a third of c/c++ programmers.

I would suggesting printing the value of 'size' to test my hypothesis!

Now if size does come out to be corrupt, and extremely high, next question is 
why at least 3 values are not printed on the screen.  The answer there is 
that the FILE structure, to which printf writes ( stdout is a FIFO*), does 
buffering, writing to OS only when it's internal buffer is full.  To debug
these kinds of problems, put a fflush(stdout) after each printf().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I found that the error was in swap function
    swap(&(maxheap->array[0]),&(maxheap->array[maxheap->size]));

It should be 
    swap(&(maxheap->array[0]),&(maxheap->array[maxheap->size - 1]));

This fixed the issue.